# Merge two observables in angular for CSV to JSON conversion

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I have a `csv` file and I want to conver it into a `JSON`.

I' m reading the CSV file with `HttpClient` and then I'm using [csvToJson](https://github.com/Keyang/node-csvtojson) to convert it.

This test code works:

```js
this.httpClient
      .get('assets/csv/results.csv', { responseType: 'text' })
      .subscribe(
        (data) => {
          csv()
            .fromString(data)
            .subscribe((jsonObj) => console.log(jsonObj));
        }
      );
```

But when I try to merge the two observables to create a function:

```js
  convert() {
    this.httpClient
      .get('assets/csv/results.csv', { responseType: 'text' })
      .pipe(switchMap((d) => csv().fromString(d)))
      .subscribe((c) => console.dir(c));
  }
```

I get this error:

```
core.js:4352 ERROR TypeError: You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.
    at subscribeTo (subscribeTo.js:27)
    at innerSubscribe (innerSubscribe.js:69)
    at SwitchMapSubscriber._innerSub (switchMap.js:44)
    at SwitchMapSubscriber._next (switchMap.js:34)
    at SwitchMapSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
    at MapSubscriber._next (map.js:35)
    at MapSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
    at FilterSubscriber._next (filter.js:33)
    at FilterSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (mergeMap.js:70)
    at SimpleInnerSubscriber._next (innerSubscribe.js:10)
    at SimpleInnerSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http.js:1678)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:399)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:27474)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:398)
```

#### Update

I've created a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-2ksumy?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/app/csv-2-json.service.ts) to experiment.

In the stackblitz I get an error I don't get on localhost:

```js
Error in src/app/csv-2-json.service.ts (18:24)
This expression is not callable.
Type '{ default: (param?: Partial<CSVParseParam>, options?: any) => Converter; }' has no call signatures.
```

In the library [source code](https://github.com/Keyang/node-csvtojson) I see that the `fromString()` returns a [Converter](https://github.com/Keyang/node-csvtojson/blob/master/src/Converter.ts) that implements `PromiseLike<any[]>` so I thought it should work.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I can not reproduce the case, but I see in the log that there are calls to `FilterSubscriber` while I do not see any `filter` operator in the pipe. It may be possible that `filter` is called internally by `httpClinet.get` but I am not sure and therefore I wonder if the log you are showing is the right one for the example.

Comment: Thanks @Picci I've provided a stackblitz link to test. In the the stackblitz now I see another error, of expression not callable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue lays with the `csvtojson` package.

First of all, if you import it via `import * as csv from "csvtojson"`, what you get in the `csv` variable is an Object which has 4 properties, 'csv' 'Converter' and 'default', each pointing to a function. So the error that you get in the stackblitz, `Type '{ default: (param?: Partial<CSVParseParam>, options?: any) => Converter; }' has no call signatures.`, means that you are trying to treat an Object as a function and invoke it. But you can not invoke an Object in Javascript.

You can make a step forward by retrieving the 'csv' function out of the `csv' Object, like this` const csvFunc = csv["csv"]`. Now in` csvFunc` you have a function you can invoke.

But at this point we step into another issue. if we do `const csvInvocationResult = csvFunc().fromString(d)` what we get is not a standard `Promise`, but an Object which accepts the `then` method, just like a regular Promise. Therefore `Object.getPrototypeOf.then(jsonFroCsv => // do something)` actually works.

Unfortunately in the Stackbliz I can not navigate through the prototype chain (I get an error while trying to execute `Object.getPrototypeOf`) so I do not know where this object inherits from. Anyways, not being a real Promise, the `switchMap` operator does not work.

I suggest you dig into `csvtojson` library to see how it works and see whether you can adjust it to return a real Promise or to find a way to convert the result it returns to a real Promise.

This answer does not resolve your issue but I hope helps cast some light into it.

Comment: Thanks for the analysis, digging into the library code I saw that it uses Bluebird [reference](https://github.com/Keyang/node-csvtojson/issues/339). There's also a [PR](https://github.com/Keyang/node-csvtojson/pull/352) to drop it still waiting. Could this be the problem?

Comment: I think this is the problem. `rxjs` works with native Promises, not Bluebird.

Comment: If you find an answer can you write an answer. Then I will delete mine :)

Answer (score 0):

**Error**

If we read the error message the following part is essential: **You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected**

**Explanation**

Your code returns an `object` somewhere in your `pipe` where instead an `observable` was expected. I expect this to happen in your `switchMap`. I have not worked with the given library but I expect `csv().fromString(d)` to return an object and not an observable.

**Solution**

I expect your code to work if you change the `object` to an `observable` by creating one via [of](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/of).

```
switchMap(d => of(csv().fromString(d)))
```

**Possible better solution**

In my opinion the `switchMap` is nonsence in your case.

**1.** If you want to stick to the above code you can just use a [map](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/map) instead:

```
map(d => csv().fromString(d))
```

**2.** If you want to merge all the previous incoming data use [scan](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/scan) to accumulate all the previous values. Then afterwards you can use `map` on all your previous data

```
scan((acc, curr) => ([...acc, ...curr]), [])
// I don't know how to accumulate your data as I did not work with the library. I now pushed all the values to an array
```

Comment: Apparently `csv.fromString`  returns a Promise, so `switchMap` should work.

Comment: I did not know that. So the usage of "of" won't work. For the sake of the "possible better" solution I will let this answer listed. Thanks for the hint +1

Comment: Thanks, I've provided a stackblitz link to test. Now I see a different error, of not callable expression (I didn't saw it on my host). I could try to use another library (or write the code on my own), but know I would like to understand what I'm doing wrong.